# Webpack: Why is minified jquery ~20kb larger than the original version?

Tags: jquery, webpack

In webpack I use `UglifyJSPlugin` to minimize all my javascript assets but jquery becomes 104 kb while `jquery.min.js` which comes with the zip package is only 85 kb. (at least in version 3.1).

[image]

I tried to use same configs as found here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L242 but it becomes slightly even  larger!

So this is config I'm using now:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  _: 'underscore',
  Backbone: 'backbone'
}),
new UglifyJSPlugin({
  parallel: true,
  sourceMap: true
}),
```

P.S. There is a small difference in other jquery plugins as well so I guess I have to adjust some UglifyJS configs...

Comment: Are you sure the minified version is 3.1? There was a lot of legacy code removed from the 3.x branch. It would make sense if the minified is v1.x or 2.x

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yep, in fact I'm using jquery@3.2.1 with webpack. Minified version is still 85kb here....

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js`? I've had success referencing min files.

Some other thoughts are to try using `mangle:true` as an UglifyJS option and even trying the [newer UglifyJS v3](https://blog.box.com/blog/how-we-improved-webpack-build-performance-95/).